# show formula with italic letter and superscript exponent in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am creating a calculator for iPhone (for practice) and I want to use the symbol x^2 without the ^ so that 2 appears directly above x. Is there a way to achieve this?

It would also be good to have an x symbol that is a bit "stylish" like the ones used in latex (e.g. such as [this](http://www.sosmath.com/soe/SE211106/img6.gif))

I am using iOS 5, XCode 4.2

Comment: Maybe you should add more details about the iOS version(s) you are targeting...

Comment: I am using iOS 5 and Xcode 4.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you mean you want to display x² in a label or button.

The easiest way is to use Unicode character U+00B2, SUPERSCRIPT TWO, which is what I did.

In Objective-C, you can put any 16-bit Unicode character in a string using a `\u` escape:

```
[self.squareButton setTitle:@"x\u00b2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

If you want to set it in Interface Builder, you can use the [Character Viewer](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/the-input-menu-and-character-viewer.php) to insert it.

Unicode also has character U+1D465 MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL X.  You can use `\U0001D465` in a string to represent that character.  Unfortunately, iOS doesn't seem to support displaying that character (in my test on the iOS 5.0 simulator).

So if you want the `x` to use an italic font but the `2` to use a regular font, you will need to use separate labels for the `x` and the `2`, or use Core Text to render an attributed string containing both characters with appropriate attributes.  As of iOS 5.1, no UIKit classes support drawing attributed strings.

Comment: Cool thanks! What about the stylish x ? (Please see the edit that I just did). Can I achieve it the same way ?

Comment: Thanks so much. By the way if I want to do it with the code, could you please tell what's a good place to add this line (sorry I am a bit newb)